# Strip hashtag off permalink with php

Tags: php, permalinks, facebook

I use the_permalink() to pass the current page to the facebook like button. But when one goes directly to a comment link with a hashtag, such as example.com/post#comment1, it's considered a separate link and FB likes are counted separately. How can I have the_permalink() point to just example.com/post and strip the #comment1?

Answer (score 1):

[`echo get_permalink($post);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), or [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) in the Loop context, will give you the canonical URL for the post, without the trailing hashtag part-- technically the 'fragment'.

You could also use PHP's [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break the URL apart if `*_permalink` functions don't work for you for some reason, or even PHP's [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for a really homegrown solution.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the `#` is **not sent per HTTP**. The browser will keep this information in memory to use the value on the target page. In PHP you cannot get this value, because PHP is running on the server.

Use a client-side script language like JavaScript.